# Mod wsgi issue regarding django apache

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache

I've been stuck in this django apache deployment. When I try to deploy my web page with linode(Linux base server) and tries to access to it, my website keeps showing this 500 Internal Server error. It happens after I ran this in my venv shell.

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

[image]

Since the web page suggest that I look into log file, which I did, I found I have mod wsgi issue. Here is my log file.

```
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388284 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035] mod_wsgi (pid=26679): Target WSGI script '/home/harryghgim/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388369 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035] mod_wsgi (pid=26679): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/harryghgim/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388622 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388720 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/home/harryghgim/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388726 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388734 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/home/harryghgim/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388739 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388745 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/home/harryghgim/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388750 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388757 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/home/harryghgim/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388760 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     self._setup(name)
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388766 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/home/harryghgim/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388770 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388777 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/home/harryghgim/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388781 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388787 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388790 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388813 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388820 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388826 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388832 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388837 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388843 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388850 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/home/harryghgim/django_project/django_project/settings.py", line 17, in <module>
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388853 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     config = json.load(config_file)
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388859 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388862 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388867 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388871 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388876 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388879 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388886 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388889 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035]     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
[Fri Feb 14 06:43:49.388909 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26679:tid 140324755478272] [remote 121.131.97.11:51035] json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 5 column 1 (char 129)
```

I'm sorry for this long log file. Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

### edit

This is my wsgi.py file at /home/harryghgim/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py

```
""" WSGI config for django_project project. It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``. For more information on this file, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/ """ 
import os from django.core.wsgi
import get_wsgi_application os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project.settings') 
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is my virtual host setting at /etc/apache2/sites-available/django_project.conf

```
Alias /static /home/harryghgim/django_project/static
<Directory /home/harryghgim/django_project/static>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /home/harryghgim/django_project/media
<Directory /home/harryghgim/django_project/media>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/harryghgim/django_project/django_project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/harryghgim/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/harryghgim/django_project python-home=/home/harryghgim/django_project/venv
WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

Should I change any of these to fix the problem?

### EDITED #2

Since it's giving me huge suffering, I rather decided to run another linux server with slightly different username and server name. And greatly I have the same issue. This time I'll try to put it neat and tidy.

```
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.657722 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046] mod_wsgi (pid=3546): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/djtu/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.658894 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046] mod_wsgi (pid=3546): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/djtu/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659151 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659254 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659291 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659319 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659324 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659331 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659335 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659341 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659346 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     self._setup(name)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659351 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659355 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659361 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659365 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659371 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659375 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659392 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659398 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659404 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659409 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659415 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659420 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659426 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/django_project/settings.py", line 17, in <module>
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659430 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     config = json.load(config_file)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659435 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659439 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659444 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659448 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659453 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659457 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659462 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659466 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046]     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.659484 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028878067456] [remote 121.131.97.11:50046] json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 6 column 1 (char 130)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850305 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045] mod_wsgi (pid=3546): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/djtu/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850350 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045] mod_wsgi (pid=3546): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/djtu/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850563 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850634 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850639 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850646 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850663 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850683 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850687 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850693 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850697 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     self._setup(name)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850702 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850706 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850711 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850715 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850721 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850724 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850730 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850735 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850741 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850747 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850752 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850758 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850763 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/home/djtu/django_project/django_project/settings.py", line 17, in <module>
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850767 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     config = json.load(config_file)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850772 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850776 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850781 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850785 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850794 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850798 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850803 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850807 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045]     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
[Sat Feb 15 06:55:00.850824 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3546:tid 140028760569600] [remote 121.131.97.11:50045] json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 6 column 1 (char 130)
```

I checked project folder permission and www-data thing. Here's my code.

```
djtu@dj-serv:~/django_project$ ls -la
total 228
drwxr-xr-x 8 djtu www-data   4096 Feb 15 06:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 15 06:55 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 djtu djtu       6148 Feb 15 05:56 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x 6 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 15 05:56 blog
-rw-rw-r-- 1 djtu www-data 167936 Feb 15 06:13 db.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x 3 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 15 06:48 django_project
-rw-r--r-- 1 djtu djtu        634 Feb 15 05:56 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 djtu www-data   4096 Feb 15 05:56 media
-rw-r--r-- 1 djtu djtu      13994 Feb 15 05:56 posts.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 djtu djtu        624 Feb 15 05:56 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x 4 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 15 06:08 static
drwxr-xr-x 5 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 15 05:56 users
drwxrwxr-x 6 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 15 06:00 venv
```

I also checked `mod_wsgi` was enabled. Here is the screenshot:

[image: mod wsgi enabled]

Just in case, I'm also putting manage.py file to see if the file is any messed up or something.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also I did `python manage.py check` in my project folder and this is shown below.

```
(venv) djtu@dj-serv:~/django_project$ python manage.py check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/djtu/django_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/djtu/django_project/django_project/settings.py", line 17, in <module>
    config = json.load(config_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 6 column 1 (char 130)
```

Here is my machine information: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu 19.10) for server and virtual host Python 3.7.5 and Django 3.0.2

Comment: Your wsgi script is not loading. Check wsgi file path and also add virtual host to provide us more information.

Comment: Go inside the project directory and run `python manage.py check` to rule out django/mod_wsgi.

Comment: @Borut Hi. I did as you said and it shows another long error messages starting with this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()

Comment: @PyMaster Hi. I'm struggling to understand what you wrote. I checked out wsgi file path and it's there obviously.. and do you want me to tell me what my virtual host is or to add something by myself in my machine? Sorry for silly question

Comment: Follow the django documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ for deploying django project using mod_wsgi. This will help you to trace any error.

Comment: @PyMaster Thanks. I added some more info. Can you please check out for me?

Comment: Check mod_wsgi mod in apache is enabled or not? Also checks the project folder permissions amd sets to www-data.

Comment: If manage.py check wasn't clean, this basically means, that you have an issue with Django, not with Apache/mod_wsgi. Start fixing there until check passes. In the horrible copy/paste in your post I see logging mentioned. Could be permission or path issue in the logging setting or just some syntax issue.

Comment: @PyMaster I tried adding some info with what you suggested. Hope I did enough. Can you please check it out? It'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @Borut I added my manage.py code. Can you please check if you don't mind? Thanks.

Comment: `config = json.load(config_file)` in the settings.py fails. config_file is not in JSON format and cannot be decoded. As error message suggests, you need to use double quotes in JSON.

Comment: @Borut That was it! Thank you so much! Actually what I messed up was not double quotes, which I already had set, but comma at the end of data. Lesson learnt anyway: json is never the same as python..Thank you again and have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up with json file format. I shouldn't have put comma at the end of data. Instead this,

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3",}
```

I set as follows.

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}
```

And it worked beautifully.